# exchange web services: export item which larger than 2GB got 400 with empty response

Tags: email, upload, exchangewebservices, transfer-encoding

I am writing a exchange client to backup and restore emails. using **ews api**. using python3 urllib send xml format (soap) http post body. The Authentication Method is ntlm. The exchange server is exchange 2016, IIS version is IIS 10.

The Ews apis I am using are: **ExportItems** and **UploadItems**.

There are some emails which are extreme large, eg. 2GB. I can export email by ExportItems, but I cannot upload with UploadItems it. server response is HTTP 400 Bad Request with empty body. The configuration and detail are as follows:

**EWS Configuration was changed as this:**

maxAllowedContentLength changed to the uint32 maximum 4294967295  (4294967295 bytes = 4GB)
maxRequestLength changed to 3000000 (3000000 kB > 4GB)
maxReceivedMessageSize changed to 4294967295 (4294967295 bytes = 4GB)

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/ews/" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering /requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSAnonymousHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site/ews/" -section:system.web/httpRuntime /maxRequestLength:3000000
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.web/httpRuntime /maxRequestLength:3000000
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSAnonymousHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSBasicHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSBasicHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSNegotiateHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSNegotiateHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecurityHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecurityHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecuritySymmetricKeyHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecuritySymmetricKeyHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecurityX509CertHttpsBinding']".httpsTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /customBinding."[name='EWSWSSecurityX509CertHttpBinding']".httpTransport.maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /webHttpBinding."[name='EWSStreamingNegotiateHttpsBinding']".maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "Exchange Back End/ews/" -section:system.serviceModel/bindings /webHttpBinding."[name='EWSStreamingNegotiateHttpBinding']".maxReceivedMessageSize:4294967295
```

I tried as follows:

1. Since exchange server using **HTTP 1.1 Transfer-Encoding: chunked** response header to response when I use **ExportItems**. I suggest that request can also use this. But even if I send valid data to server with **Transfer-Encoding: chunked**, the server give me a HTTP 1.1 400 Bad Request with no response data?

the ews api don't support **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** request? If anyone succeed using **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** ews api, please share to me.

2. using Content-Length. but when I set  Content-Length larger than 2GB, e.g. set Content-Length: 2247483648 which larger than 2,147,483,648. The server give me a HTTP 1.1 400 Bad Request with no response data.

but use Content-Length < 2GB is OK. Is there another configuration controll the 2GB limit?